# Redux store delay

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I would really appreciate some help on a strategy. In my react/redux app, I have an array list of messages, and when I click on an individual message, I go to a component which takes the id params of that message and fetches it from the database. The problem is every time I click on a message it shows the old redux store message for a second before the store updates.

My only fix was to dispatch an action in componentDidUnmount to clear the store. Is this the best strategy to handle this? The only other way I thought of is instead of hitting the database for the individual message, I loop through the redux store array using filter to pull out the post that matches the params id. Is this too 'heavy' to loop through them all, or am I better off hitting the database? A problem with this is if someone loads the individual message page first without visiting the 'feed' and the store array would be empty...

This is my component:

```
class Post extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
  const id = this.props.match.params.id;
  this.props.startGetPost(id);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.props.getPost({});  
}

  render() {

    const { post, loading } = this.props.post;
    let postContent;


    if (loading) {
      postContent = <Spinner />
    }

    if (post && post) {
      postContent = (
        <div>
        <PostItem post={post} />
        <CommentForm postId={post._id} />
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: Where is the data coming from? An API? If so, are you redux-thunk or something else?

Comment: Yes a node express server and mongodb database. I am using redux thunk for the action.

Comment: you can add a property in redux store message payload isLoading and on click make it true and when you get the new data make it false. You can do this in action creators. on click action loading true and on receive false

Answer (score 2):

In your reducer, you'll need to specify a flag for your `loading` state, since the data is coming from an API.

In your container, you must provide the `loading` flag to your component using `react-redux`'s `connect`, once your component have access to the `loading` prop, you can use it to check if your data isn't ready and give some feedback to your user.

***Usually***, async operations involves 3 Redux Actions to represent data beign fetched. In your case, you would have actions like:

```
- GET_MESSAGE_FETCHING
- GET_MESSAGE_SUCCESS
- GET_MESSAGE_FAIL
```

In your reducer, you can manipulate your state to handle these actions, toggling `loading` to `true` when fetching and `false` on success or fail.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Vinhas, thank you. I have a loading flag. The individual message is getting set, and when I click on a new one message, the loading flag is set to true but the individual post is set to the old one before it reloads, so my if statement (see my original post) still displays the old one for about half a second.

Comment: Nevermind, it was an issue with my if else statement logic. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No worries, It happens :)